# webdav file server client in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webdav

I am coding a webdav client winforms application in c# for basic ftp functionalities. I wonder if there is an open source api for webdav ftp functions. If not and i have to code it from scratch where should is  start ? whats the best documentation to write c# libray for webdav server.

Comment: its not an ftp server. its an http server.

Comment: httpwebrequest returns html resutl.i should do too much parsing to extract the required info. Isnt there a simpler way ?

Answer (score 1):

Start from learning current clients/servers and WebDAV documentation.
Here is the best documentation for WebDAV: [http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/common-index.html)
And for HttpWebRequest - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=HttpWebRequest&ac=3)